# Next button not working in content of a slider

Tags: javascript

Question is how to force "next" button to work inside div content (slide)

What iam trying to do is to put next button:

```
<button id="next" class="js-btn btn">next</button>
```

into the content of a slide, after text "one", "two" etc.

```
<div id="one" class="cur item js-fade fade-in">one</div>
```

So it should look like that:

```
<div id="one" class="cur item js-fade fade-in">
  one<br>
  <button id="next" class="js-btn btn">next</button>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0n0ff/mjjec7oe/

Comment: Well, what's the question?

Comment: How to do next button to work inside div content 
<div id="one" class="cur item js-fade fade-in">one</div>

Comment: Edit to the question..

Comment: The next button doesn't *do* anything.  You assign meaning through handlers in javascript.  There is also no reason to assume that a button that works outside a div wouldn't work inside of one unless an error in the handler results in the button not working properly.

Comment: i see, its not working cause iam trying to use two or more buttons with the same id "next" so if i do button with new id it will work

Comment: it works like i wrote - 
https://jsfiddle.net/0n0ff/mjjec7oe/2/